# Promise then() and catch() UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` when I run this simple code:

```
var d = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (false) {
    resolve('hello world');
  } else {
    reject('no bueno');
  }
});

d.then((data) => console.log('success : ', data));

d.catch((error) => console.error('error : ', error));
```

The complete response is:

```
error :  no bueno
(node:12883) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: no bueno
(node:12883) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:12883) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Seems like `d.catch()` is being fired. I noticed that if comment out `d.then()`, the warning message disappears.

I'm calling the script from the terminal like `node foobar.js`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Tested with node v8.14, v10 and v11 under MacOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d.then()` creates a new promise that is rejected because `d` is rejected. That is the rejected promise that is not handled correctly.

You should chain `.then` and `.catch` instead:

```
d
  .then((data) => console.log('success : ', data))
  .catch((error) => console.error('error : ', error));
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Gave a complete read to the documentation and it turns out that it's well documented: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value